# Verify that every tangent plane to the cone $x^2+y^2-z^2 = 0$ passes through the origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm supposed to show that every tangent plane to the cone $x^2+y^2-z^2 = 0$ passes through the origin.

I set $f(x) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2$ and calculated the gradient of f.

$\nabla f = \langle 2x,2y,-2z\rangle$

Then I found the equation of the tangent plane at the point $P=(a,b,c)$.

$\langle2a,2b,-2c\rangle\bullet\langle x-a,y-b,z-c\rangle=0$

The problem is, $(0,0,0)$ is not a solution to that equation. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You left off a minus sign.

Comment: you forgot a minus sign $\langle 2a,2b-2c\rangle$

Comment: I don't think so... The gradient is normal to the surface.

Comment: I remember having to do that at some point during this class, but the links you sent me and the answers in the back of my book seem to agree with me. For example, the example at the bottom of this page: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GradientVectorTangentPlane.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is! Since $P=(a,b,c)$ is a point of the cone, it satisfies
$$a^2+b^2-c^2=0.$$
Now, try substituting $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ in your equation and see what happens.

Comment: $\langle2a,2b,-2c\rangle\bullet\langle 0-a,0-b,0-c\rangle=0$

$$-2a^2-2b^2+2c^2=0$$

Comment: OH I get it. And since $P$ satisfies the equation for the cone, it is equal to 0. Thanks

Comment: "It" being the second equation in the first comment